# Long press animation with Swift UI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a long press gesture that highlights another button. The code looks like the following:

```
@GestureState var highlight = false

var body: some View {
    var longPress: some Gesture {
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
            .updating($highlight) { currentstate, gestureState, transaction in
                gestureState = currentstate
                transaction.animation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2.0)
            }
    }
    Text("highlight!")
        .gesture(longPress)
    Button(...) { ... }
        .accentColor(self.highlight ? .green : .none)                   
}
```

How do I make sure that the transitions from `.none` accent to `.green` accent and back are more smooth? At the moment it switches rather abruptly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.accentColor` is not animatable modifier, however you can achieve the same effect (as soon as I understood) with the following approach.

[image: demo]

```
struct TestLongPressGesture: View {
    @GestureState var highlight = false
    var body: some View {
        var longPress: some Gesture {
            LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
                .updating($highlight) { currentstate, gestureState, transaction in
                    transaction.animation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2.0)
                    gestureState = currentstate
                }
        }
        return VStack {
            Text("highlight!")
                .gesture(longPress)
            Divider()
            Button("Button") { }
                .font(Font.largeTitle.bold())
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .colorMultiply(self.highlight ? .green : .blue)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: highlight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks considerably better, however, I only see the `easeOut` animation. Also in dark mode, the multiplication produces rather violet colour, and not green.

Comment: Took me a while to get it working. There's an additional `.animation(.easeInOut)` after `colorMultiply` on your button missing.